# How to create a floating collapsable panel

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a fixed/floating right aligned help button on my website that when clicked expands to take up a specificWidth by maxHeight section on the screen on the right side as a way to provide help to users.

```css
.floating-help-section {
    background-color: #fbd850;
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 2000; !important;
}

.help-accordion {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: #444444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s
}

.help-panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="floating-help-section">
        <button class="help-accordion">Help</button>
        <div class="help-panel">
            This is where the help content goes
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code above is a start in the right direction, it doesn't float on the right yet among a few smaller issues. My main issue is that I don't know how to force a specific uncollapsed/expanded size for my help panel to get it to expand nicely and have a good amount of space to show my content.

Comment: is this help button going to show up multi times with dynamic informations , or just ones with static informations ?

Comment: I'm hoping to make it available site wide with dynamic information

Comment: so you're bringing those dynamic help informations using Ajax from another page ? if so javascript can be very handy in stuff like this especially jquery , and we can provide multi solution if so .

other ways if you bring them using only 'php' directly and outputting  them into a hidden html tags or you just writing them directly in an hidden html code without any php programming
then you only need css , you could use javascript but css is enough in that case

Comment: @kakashisenpai I'm planning on using an iFrame to display an external page, it will be from salesforce. I'm trying to work through the best way to do this which is why I'm attempting it this way at the moment